# What are the rules for automatic upcasting of functions?

Tags: f#

In my code I have a scenario where I'd like F# to automatically upcast values of one function type (e.g. `IBase -> unit`) to another, explicitly specified function type (`IDerived -> unit`). While this seems to be generally supported, I found cases where it fails for no obvious reason.

In the code below, `case1` to `case8` seem equivalent to me: In each case, there's an expression of type `IBase -> unit` on the right hand side that is bound to a name of type `IDerived -> unit`. So why are cases 4, 5 and 7 not allowed?

```
type IBase = interface end
type IDerived = inherit IBase

let foo (x: IBase) = ()
let bar = fun (x: IBase) -> ()

type T = T with static member (!!) (_: T) = foo
let baz = !!T

let case1: IDerived -> unit = foo                               // OK
let case2: IDerived -> unit = bar                               // OK
let case3: IDerived -> unit = baz                               // OK
let case4: IDerived -> unit = !!T                               // Expecting 'IDerived -> unit' but given 'IBase -> unit'
let case5: IDerived -> unit = upcast !!T                        // Type 'IBase -> unit' is not compatible with type 'IDerived -> unit'
let case6: IDerived -> unit = let z = !!T in z                  // OK
let case7: IDerived -> unit = fun (x: IBase) -> ()              // Expected x to have type 'IDerived' but here has type 'IBase'
let case8: IDerived -> unit = let z = fun (x: IBase) -> () in z // OK
```

EDIT: To clarify, I'm mostly wondering why the 8 cases are not treated equally by the compiler. For example, I'd expect the binding `let z...` in `case8` to be superfluous, yet it makes a difference (compared to `case7`). Why?

EDIT: Here's some code to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AlpdpO It also contains a solution/workaround, so I'm really asking more for technical details/reasons rather than alternative approaches. I thought about raising an issue on GitHub already, but feel like the issue is most likely just a misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: A function that takes an `IDerived` parameter can never be treated as a function that takes an `IBase`, because, well, it just doesn't. Your function type would be `IBase -> unit` from looking at it, but what's supposed to happen when you call it with an `IBase` parameter that's not `IDerived`?

Comment: But the opposite works: A function taking an `IBase` can be treated as a function taking an `IDerived`. `IBase -> unit` is a subtype of `IDerived -> unit`, hence upcasting should generally work I guess.

Comment: I think it might be related to https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/660. If it is indeed that, then a fix was proposed, but it had to be pulled due to breaking older code: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5246.

Comment: converting a function to one with parameters higher or lower on the class hierarchy is called "covariance" and "contravariance," features that aren't supported in F#.  Usually the way to do it in F# would be to have a `'a -> unit when 'a :> IBase`, which can be simplified as `#IBase -> unit`

Comment: (that might not be the exact syntax)

Comment: If contravariance is not supported, why does the majority of cases compile just fine?

Comment: _In the future we don't need roads..._ -> In F# we [mostly] don't need to use interfaces, casts, and many other C#-like concepts. Perhaps if you could, please, explain what you _really_ need to do (without getting into implementation details), then an F#-like solution could be found.

Comment: Your solution is very elegant, much better than the interfaces. Compilers are very complicated and not perfect, you just found a glitch and a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F#'s type inference doesn't seem to be quite smart enough to handle some of those cases, but you can help it out by making your definitions of a little bit more explicit.  Try this:

```
type IBase = interface end
type IDerived = inherit IBase

let foo (x: IBase) = ()

type T = T with static member (!!) (_: T) : #IBase -> unit = foo

let case4: IDerived -> unit = !!T
let case5: IDerived -> unit = upcast !!T
let case7: IDerived -> unit = fun (x: #IBase) -> ()
```

...and, of course, your original passing cases will continue to pass as well.  The issue is that F# has been a little bit too strict about the type of the (!!) function and the type of the lambda, so we can help it out with an explicit type annotation that says "`IBase` or any of its derivatives are fine here".

By all means, file a bug for these syntactic cases.  It's not a terribly bad thing for a compiler to err on the side of caution when it comes to types, as the F# compiler has done here.  Far worse things can happen if it's too lenient.  Here, the worst effect is that you've got to do some of the typing-work for it.

I should point out that this really has nothing to do with casting and there's no casting that happens (the `upcast` is ignored).  The real issue is strictness of interpretation.  Try this code out and you'll see the warning that indicates that.